# Static view above Shell Bottom Tabbar in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Shell in my Xamarin Forms app together with a bottom tabbar and no flyout menu.

Is it somehow possible to have a static view/control between the content page and the bottom tabbar?
(As an example, look at Spotifys mini-player that's constantly shown above the bottom tabbar)

I have tried to use a ControlTemplate in the ContentPage, but it works so-so.
When navigating between pages, the entire view is "slided away", thus it's noticeable that the control is not static and instead instantiated per each page.

Deactivating animations partially solves it but makes the application feel very static and is thus not an acceptable solution.

Anyone got an idea of how this can be solved?

It's quite easy to solve it with Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.Ios, but this needs to be done in Xamarin Forms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, if it is easy to achieve in native, you could have a try with [custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers) to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks, but thats not as easy: It would require me to use a custom renderer for the entire ShellPage since the full layout needs to be updated, so I do not think that's an option.

Comment: Okey, Xamarin Forms Shell not provides the methods to achieve that, using renderer should be the best option.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go for that approach.

Comment: Great, if finish that, you could share the solution in answer later.